# NLog unable to create log file on Linux server (ASP.NET Core application)

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, ubuntu, nginx, nlog

It is working fine on the local windows system. When I deploy it on a Linux server it is neither logging logs nor creating log files.

nlog.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          autoReload="true"
          throwConfigExceptions="true">    
      
      <!-- enable asp.net core layout renderers -->
      <extensions>
        <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
      </extensions>
    
      <!-- the targets to write to -->
      <targets>
        <target 
          name="errorLogFile"
          xsi:type="File" 
          fileName="${currentdir}/logs/error/${date:format=yyyyMMdd}.txt"
          layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${callsite}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring} ${newline} "
          />
        
        <target 
          name="infoLogFile"
          xsi:type="File"
          fileName="${currentdir}/logs/info/${date:format=yyyyMMdd}.txt"
          layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${callsite}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring} ${newline} " 
          />    
      </targets>
      <rules>
        <logger name="Microsoft.*" minlevel="Info" maxlevel="Warn" writeTo="" final="true" />
        <logger name="*" minlevel="ERROR" writeTo="errorLogFile" />
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" maxlevel="Warn"  writeTo="infoLogFile" />
      </rules>
    </nlog>
```

Program.cs > CreateHostBuilder

```
            .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
            {
                logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
                logging.AddConsole();
                logging.AddDebug();
                logging.AddEventSourceLogger();
                // Enable NLog as one of the Logging Provider
                logging.AddNLog();
            })
```

Comment: Ensure you are not depending on NLog.config-nuget-package. Ensure NLog.config is deployed. Ensure file permissions are correct. Try to enable NLog InternalLogger from code. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting

Comment: You should add write permission to folder to create files.

Comment: @FarhadZamani, I've already given permission to the folder using the "Chmod 777 folder_name" command.

Comment: @Riteshyadav Instead of using `${currentdir}` then use an explicit path, which has the correct file-permissions.

Comment: @RolfKristensen I tried this but didn't get any success and it worked when I renamed the "nLog.config" file to "NLog.config".

Comment: Yes `nlog.config` (all lowercase) is the most predictable.